# Can I use NSSpeechSynthesizer from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cocoa, macos, text-to-speech, speech

I have a short and simple question: Can I use NSSpeechSynthesizer or Mac OS's Text-to-Speech engine from JavaScript (if I'm on a Mac using Safari)? And if so: how?

Thanks!

- Johannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't a way without plugins

A java applet may be able to, but it would likely have to ask the user for permission first.